# Getting null pointer exception, showing as cannot invoke "dataProviders.ConfigFileReader.getImplicitlyWait()" because "this.configFileReader" is null

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java

```
public void select_item() {
        
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(configFileReader.getImplicitlyWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            home = pageObjectManager.getHomePage();
            home.clickon_item();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void select_item() {
  configFileReader = new ConfigFileReader();
  driver
    .manage()
    .timeouts()
    .implicitlyWait(
      configFileReader.getImplicitlyWait(),
      TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );

  home = pageObjectManager.getHomePage();
  home.clickon_item();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.